# Mockito.when() throws Exception when called for the second time

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have an Api class that can make an api call. It just takes a Long and an Integer as Arguments. I call this api in a controller class, which handles the potential errors when calling the api. Essentially it's just this:

```
public String save() {
    try {
        String rc = api.doApiCall(l, i);
        if(rc.equals("200"))
            return "nextpage.html";
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {

    }
    return "error.html";
}
```

I want to test this controller. I'm mocking the api like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    controller = new Controller();
    api = mock(Api.class);
    controller.api = api;
}
    
@Test
void testApiCall() {
    when(api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class)))
        .thenReturn("200");
    
    assertEquals("nextpage.html", controller.save());
        
    when(api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class)))
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("400"));
        
    assertEquals("error.html", controller.save());
        
    when(api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class)))
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("401"));
    assertEquals("error.html", controller.save());
}
```

However executing this test fails at the third when() call because the exception specified in the second when() call is thrown. How can i fix this and why does it happen?

I already experimented a bit and found out that, if you replace the `any(Integer.class)` in the third when() call with just `any()` the test works as expected but now adding a third test case like

```
when(api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any()))
    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("402"));
assertEquals("error.html", controller.save());
```

fails with the exact same problem as above.

Comment: IMHO, each of these scenarios should be a separate test case -- this would give you a "clean" state for the mock for each of the tests.

Comment: Exactly what @lealceldeiro said, those are different test cases, split them in different tests. Problem solved and as a bonus you get cleaner unit tests.

Comment: You can stub consecutive calls: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_consecutive_calls, but my vote also goes for splitting your code into separate test methods.

Comment: Yeah for these test cases multiple methods are way better. But in reality the test also require a static mock, filling a bean and more. And having this in 10 seperate methods seems a bit too much.
There is also still the question why, because this is almost copy pasted from another test that does the same thing. But there it works like this.

Comment: Since it is `almost copy pasted`, you can't really expect the same behaviour. And you should do the setup in `@BeforeEach`, if it's the same (you are doing it once in the beginning of the test, so it should be the same).

Comment: I can't expect the same behaviour for everything i'm doing. But since it's the same setup just with different arguments in the api call i still expected this to work because it doesn't occur to me why it shouldn't. 
I only setup things in `@BeforeEach` if they are needed in every test in that class. Is it better to stuff everything in there?

Comment: Everything? Of course no, only the common setup. But since you are doing this setup once in the beginning of the big test case, it appears that it is a common setup for everything. If it's specific for one (or a few) test cases only, you can always extract it in a method and call it where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is always preferable to have distinct test cases for distinct tests - and testing the different reactions to different API results are different test cases.

The problem is that when you write

```
when(api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class)))
```

you are actually calling `api.doApiCall()` on the `api` mock and this exercises the previously registered behaviour.

- On the first call there is no previously registered behaviour and `api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class))` returns null and later mockito registers a return value of "200" for succeeding calls.
- On the second call there is a previosuly registered behaviour and
  `api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class))` returns "200" and later mockito registers to throw an exception for succeeding calls.
- On the third call there is another previously registered behaviour and `api.doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class))` throws `new RuntimeException("400")`

You can avoid this problem if you write

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("401"))
    .when(api).doApiCall(any(Long.class), any(Integer.class));
```

But this has still the potential to create unwanted coupling between your distinct tests.

Comment: Thank you. This answers it. Just want to write all my findings here:
the `any()` workaround does work for just one test case because `any()` returns null which isn't matched by `any(Class<?> type)` but does not work for consecutive calls as 'any()' matches null.
In the other test i mentioned it worked because i was using a custom class so `any(MyClass.class)` always called with the not matched null, but in case of primitives and their wrappers like Integer, `any(Class<?> type)` will return a default value != null.

Comment: Mockitos Java Doc indiciates that `any(Class<?> type)` always returns null though.